# Gradle use in a disparate build system

Tags: java, maven, gradle

I have been wondering what the right approach is to using Gradle in an environment with disparate but dependent projects.

For example, suppose I have a docker image build that depends on a separate (say, Dropwizard) application build, while that's dependent on a common utilities library. What's the right way to make a change in the utilities, use that change in the application code, and get those changes into the docker image, without multiple full continuous integration release cycles?

In Maven, it all happens by default. I simply build (install) each of them and as long as my dependencies are correct (right group/artifact/versions) it "just works."

Alternatively I can check out all 3 projects and create a simple very small super-pom with a modules section that lists the 3 underlying projects and building from there automatically sorts out the dependencies, ordering the build appropriately, and my changes are cascaded through the dependencies. I can load this pom into Eclipse and all of the inter-relationships are automatically determined and picked up.

It seems like Gradle has no concept of a local repository out of the box. The Gradle cache is nothing more than a performance implementation detail and not a local repository. This seems exacerbated by the lack of the concept of a SNAPSHOT version in Gradle.

So what is the right way to approach this in Gradle? Thanks.

Comment: Use `mavenLocal()` repository in your `build.gradle` config `repositories` config (or other local/internal repo). Also the current gradle version has the concept of different-directory multiprojects (cant remember the specific name right now).

Comment: Thanks @cjstehno. Unless I'm missing something, that doesn't seem to help unless I'm integrating maven projects with Gradle. How do I get Gradle builds INTO the maven local by default? Do I need a 3rd party plugin to do that? Doesn't this seem like part of a normal development process that anyone would want to do? Gradle doesn't do this out of the box?

Comment: Use the Maven plugin and run `publishToMavenLocal`.

Comment: Thanks @cjstehno. This gets me most of what I need.